# Memory usage concern when using HTTPS for web services or web requests

Tags: c#, .net, memory, https

EDIT: After a long discussion in the comments, it seems that my original question didn't really capture what was going on.  Here's a summary of where I am now:

- When using HTTPS, there's what I would consider a dramatic jump in the virtual memory space of my application (typically from under 50mb to over 200mb) when the first HTTPS request (web service call, WebClient.DownloadFile(), etc.) is made
- At the same time, a CPU core also moves to nearly 100% usage.  This typically only lasts a few seconds, but I have seen it last longer
- It may very well be the case that this is just the cost of using HTTPS, but I was surprised by it since I had never noticed it before in other apps (and other developers on my team never noticed it in this app, which has been using HTTPS since long before I came on board).
- The kicker: this doesn't appear to happen on all machines, but does on most.  If it happened consistently on every machine, I'd be more willing to accept it as a "cost of doing business."  But since there does seem to be a difference between some machines running the same code and OS, I would like to understand why that is since it will either a) allow us to mitigate the behavior, or b) explain it in a way that satisfies non-technical higher-ups that it's not actually a "problem", as explaining that Windows Task Manager shows virtual memory and not necessarily actively-in-use physical memory hasn't been satisfactory so far :/

I've left the original post intact below in case anyone is interested, but it focuses more on web services, which aren't really at the root of the problem.

Thanks in advance for any further insight!

---

We're seeing memory usage increase dramatically whenever our application first makes a call to our web service using https.  The specifics vary by machine, but as an example we may see our application jump from ~50mb to over 250mb when the first web service call is made, and the usage never climbs back down.  Subsequent calls do not result in another such jump.  I can reproduce the behavior with the code below (not specific to our application) and a public web service that we do not own - so it seems to be independent of both our client- and server-side code.

Interestingly, in my test app I don't observe this jump on Windows XP (our application is currently deployed only on Windows 7).  We also don't see it on every dev/test machine in the office (but we do on most), and we don't currently have a way to retrieve this info from machines out in the "real world."

I haven't been able to pin down what's being allocated, but several profilers have made it clear that it resides in native (not managed) memory.  Analysis of some WinDbg dumps using DebugDiag leaves me to believe that there is a lot of memory getting allocated in crypt32.dll that isn't being released.  This makes sense to some extent (https implies certificates, security, etc., and it's likely that whatever is being loaded is getting cached, hence why subsequent calls don't result in additional jumps), but I have a hard time believing this is really just the cost of using https for a web service.

I know there will be some responses from the "if higher memory usage isn't causing problems, why worry?" camp.  In general I agree - the memory usage numbers in Task Manager often aren't indicative of whether the app is working as intended.  If the app was used strictly in-house, I could live with this as long as it wasn't a symptom of other problems.  But our app is deployed with consumer machines, so we have to worry about the *perception* of a problem just as much as the actual problem.  So if there's any way to fix this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Finally, the web service that I use in the test code below is available here: http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx?wsdl.  The code for EmailVerNoTestEmail was generated using the wsdl.exe tool, with the slight modification of passing the URL as a parameter to the constructor rather than hard-coding it (so that http/https can be specified on the fly).

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string urlSuffix = "://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx";
    string protocol = null;
    while(protocol == null)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter protocol (http, https): ");
        var line = Console.ReadLine();
        if (line != null) line = line.ToLower();
        if (line == "http" || line == "https")
            protocol = line.Trim();
    }
    var url = protocol + urlSuffix;
    Console.WriteLine("Using URL: " + url);
    Console.Out.Flush();

    var service = new EmailVerNoTestEmail(url);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to make the web service call...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);

    Console.WriteLine("Calling web service...");
    var resp = service.VerifyEmail("test@gmail.com", "test");
    Console.WriteLine("Response: " + resp);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Comment: Why is this a problem? Are you running out of memory?

Comment: Also, changed the title, as this is not a "spike". A spike goes up sharply, then goes down sharply.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Thanks for the wording fix, I knew "spike" wasn't quite right but couldn't figure out how to word it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: As I explained in the post, there's no direct evidence of any specific problems, but the memory numbers have caught the eye of higher-ups, and for better or worse there has thus been organizational pressure to get those numbers down.  It may ultimately be the case that this is something we just have to accept, but I'd like to know that definitively before I dismiss it, since it's generally quite repeatable and just seems out of whack - in my opinion, anything that suddenly quadruples your footprint is worth looking into even if it's not causing immediate problems.

Comment: It actually seems precisely the normal pattern for a change in memory usage after a feature is used for the first time. I can't imagine what your higher-ups want to hear. Are you sure they wouldn't be satisfied with a load test that shows that the memory usage doesn't increase substantially over time?

Comment: Also, please (politely) teach your higher-ups about virtual memory? They may not realize that the system has no reason not to allocate address space as soon as it's needed, and to not release the address space unless that address space is needed by some other process.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: To be perfectly honest I don't believe that this is "new" behavior (https web service calls were in use in the product since long before I started), but at some point a few months ago an outside observer commented negatively on the memory usage, setting a few on a warpath to "fix it."  I've tried to explain that if memory usage is stable then the specific number is less important, but as I'm sure you can imagine it's often not easy to convey that message to a non-technical audience, particularly one that is sensitive to having their product perceived negatively.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: All that being said, even if this is a "cost of doing business" so-to-speak when using https, then if nothing else I'd like to become educated on what's happening under the hood here, since that might enable me to make a more specific/convincing argument about why we don't need to spend resources addressing this.

Comment: Good luck. You're looking into the implementation details of a legacy technology. You'd do better learning how to educate your non-technical audience.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Is there a newer/better implementation out there for calling web services in C# that you would recommend?  I'd definitely be open to alternative libraries.  I don't have any allegiance to  using wsdl.exe/SoapHttpClientProtocol; it's just what was there when I inherited the code.

Comment: Sorry, I usually say this first: don't use "Add Web Reference" or any other part of the legacy ASMX stack. Use WCF: "Add Service Reference" and svcutil.exe. If nothing else, if it somehow turns out this is a bug, then it may get fixed. There is almost no chance of an ASMX bug getting fixed.

Comment: Also, are you management really not able to understand why a different amount of memory might be used in an https connection vs. http? Doing something (encryption) vs. doing nothing (no encryption) is likely to take more memory.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into using svcutil.  The problem that I'm having with just explaining this away is twofold: 1) the magnitude of the jump - does using https really mean the footprint of an otherwise very simple app has to quadruple?  I totally get that https costs more, but does it really require dragging in hundreds of MB of additional unmanaged data? ; and 2) this doesn't happen on every system - for whatever reason, a handful machines don't exhibit this behavior.  I'd be okay saying "this isn't a problem, it's just how it works" - but it's *not* how it works in every case.

Comment: it's not a "footprint". It's virtual memory. The address space grew, not necessarily the memory usage. And, yes, there's a _huge_ difference in the code and data necessary to encrypt and decrypt SSL traffic versus the code and data needed to _not_ encrypt and decrypt SSL traffic. Good luck explaining "how sausage is made" to people who don't have the ability to understand you.

Comment: Fair enough, "footprint" was not really what I meant (I understand the difference between physical and virtual memory) - but regardless the memory usage MUST be increasing at least briefly at some point (especially if the cost of using https is apparently so much larger than I realized).  Regardless, as I said before, I don't think this is new behavior; I just think nobody noticed until fairly recently.  If I reproduce this in an older version, maybe it will settle everyone down and convince them that our behavior didn't suddenly get worse, and I can move on.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do try to remember that using HTTPS instead of HTTP involves referencing a bunch of new code (the encryption code, plus the code to insert the encryption into the TCP streams, the code to maintain the SSL session, etc) along with all the data necessary to perform these functions. It makes no sense that memory usage would _not_ grow the first time all this new cod and data are referenced.

Comment: I would also try some experiments using just `HttpWebRequest` to make sure of where in the networking stack the memory usage is coming from. It may have nothing to do with the fact that it's a web service. You should also check to see if there is more usage when there are _two_ HTTPS connections, both in the web service and the WebRequest cases.

Comment: Again, I'm not surprised it's growing, I absolutely would expect it to increase.  It was the scale of the increase that surprised me.
I reproduced the behavior using WebClient.DownloadFile(), so it doesn't appear to be specific to web services.  Interestingly, if I fire off two DownloadFileAsync() operations concurrently, I do see the VM increase by roughly twice as much as before, but eventually settle back to the "usual" higher amount.  If I run them sequentially, the first one causes a jump, but the second one doesn't.  Lends further evidence to it being a one-time startup cost.

Comment: Also, one thing I've failed to mention this whole time, during the run-up in memory, one core of the CPU is getting pegged.  In the parallel case above, two cores get pegged; in the sequential case, the second request happens very quickly and doesn't seem to hit the CPU particularly hard.
I haven't tried multiple web service requests (parallel or sequential) yet, but I do see a pegged core during the VM increase with HTTPS web service calls.
No idea if that's useful, could just be the system working hard to allocate that memory for HTTPS.

Comment: Memory allocation doesn't require much CPU time. it's more likely doing something with encryption.

Comment: That makes sense.  I grabbed a dump using ADPlus while it was in the "pegged" state, and the stack trace does seem to be dealing with X509 certificates.  Is it possible that the size of the certificate store on the client machine (or something along those lines) would have an impact on this?  I ask because, as I mentioned before, not all machines seem to exhibit this behavior, and I'm trying to think of possible system/environmental differences since the code and URLs are the same.  At this point the difference between machines is more disconcerting to me than the behavior itself.

Comment: Please take this to chat, or integrate the information in the comments back into the question.  I'm going to start deleting the comments within the next 1/2 hour.

Comment: Apologies; unfortunately I apparently don't have the rep points to start a chat (I tried earlier).  Will edit the question shortly.

Answer (score -1):

Unless a system is stressed, it is natural for it to remain at a certain memory level. The OS has heuristics which determine how much memory is needed and allocates to that high point greater than what is needed. Why? It is expensive for allocation and deallocation of memory and if a program can run in its own sandbox which was given, why decrease it if the system is not stressed.

As you mentioned it is not the amount of memory allocated which is a concern, but it is the leaking of memory. I suggest you run perfmon and monitor for leaks; read up on the things to look out for in this MSDN CLR article [Investigating Memory Issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163528.aspx).

**EDIT**: (*This is advice I have given before but may be relevant/ sorry for topic duplication*)

To see the telltale sign of memory leaks one fires up perfmon and looks at Private Bytes in perfmon for that those signs.  See [Identify And Prevent Memory Leaks In Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/msdnmag/issues/07/01/ManagedLeaks/default.aspx) to begin that process.

One other process to use is on the Processes tab of the Windows Task Manager. ( View + Select Columns,) check Handles, GDI Objects and USER Objects.  Observe these values for your program.  If there is t a handle leak, you'll see one of these steadily climbing if you do.  GDI in all likelihood under those scenarios. 
 
 In general when the OS runs an application it tries to determine how much memory is being used. It will allocate *more* memory for the application that what the application currently needs. The reason for that is, to allocate/deallocate memory is a cpu intensive operation. Why parallel what the app needs when it can reside *in a pool*  of memory which will allow it, the app, to expand and contract with no interference from the operating system. Saves on cycles.
 
 What the developer sees is a high water mark for memory. If the system is not stressed, the system *will not reclaim* any memory and keep the high water mark. There are many posts in this forum where the users say, processing done, memory cleaned up but the OS still shows my app at memory point X, when it should be memory point M (lower). Winform users report the same but if one minimizes the app, suddenly the mem usage reported drops to that M level. That is done by design. Minimizing suggests that an app doesn't need the memory for it will not be interacting with the user and the OS will reclaim the point. If its not a winform and the OS is not stressed, the app stays at the high water mark of X.